# OS Error [Errno 22] Invalid argument when exporting pix2pix model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a model on my own image dataset according to Christopher Hesses `pix2pix-tensorflow` application: https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow

When I try to export it, it raises the following error, when writing manifest.json:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>: 
 File "server/tools/export-checkpoint.py", line 102, in <module>
   main()
 File "server/tools/export-checkpoint.py", line 64, in <module> 
   with open>os.path.join>tmp_dir, value["filename"]), "rb") as f: 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temo\\tmp8q_z2rx\\generator_decoder_8_batch_normalization_gamma'
```

I am using Windows and am executing in Anaconda Prompt.

How can I best fix this issue?

The command I used was:

```
python server/tools/export-checkpoint.py --checkpoint cars_export --output_file cars_BtoA.pict
```

Best, C

Comment: Are the "..." in the path that gives the error present in the actual error or did you shorten your error message?

Comment: It just refers to the name of my PC